# How to push a new object into state without removing the previous values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to push a new object into the state variable without getting the previous values removed. My state is

```
this.state = {
files:{
    file1: 
    {
        user1:[{
                key1: val1,
                key2: val2,
                key3: val3
            },
            {
                key1: val1,
                key2: val2,
                key3: val3
            }
        ]
    }
}   
}
```

I need to update the `files` as

```
files:{
    file1: 
    {
        user1:[{
                key1: val1,
                key2: val2,
                key3: val3
            },
            {
                key1: val1,
                key2: val2,
                key3: val3
            }
        ]
    },
    file2: 
    {
        user2:[{
                key1: val1,
                key2: val2,
                key3: val3
            },
            {
                key1: val1,
                key2: val2,
                key3: val3
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to push a new object `file2` into the state having values in the same structure as `file1`. How can I update the state with these two objects?

Comment: The recommended way to achieve this is by using array destructuring. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Op%C3%A9rateurs/Affecter_par_d%C3%A9composition

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `setState` function expression, so you can access the previous state:

```
addFile(newFile) {
  this.setState(state => ({
    files: {...state.files, ...newFile}
  })
}
```

`newFile` should be an object that looks like this:

```
{
  file2: {
    ...
  }
}
```

This object gets merged into the previous state. If there already was an entry with the same key (`file2`), it would get overridden.

Comment: This gives the result as array. `file1` inside 0th key and `file2` inside 1st key. I need the keys shouls be `file1` and `file2` and not as `0` or `1`

Comment: I see. Updated my answer.

Comment: This is working @Hinrich. The objects are sorted based on the alphabetical order or keys. Eg: `File1` , `File2` etc. How can I arrange them based on the pushing order?

Comment: Objects are unsorted by nature, think of it as Sets. If order is important to you, you should store your data in an `array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using spread operator.
It can be added as follows:

```
this.setState({
    file1: [...this.state.file1,{key1:'val1',key2:'val2',key3:'val3'}]
})
```